# Валидация jsp страниц на сервере

Tags: jsp, java-ee, java

Здравствуйте! Никак не получается сделать валидацию полей на сервере. В index.jsp добавил:

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="pack.User" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>

<%
  java.util.Map errors = new java.util.HashMap();
  if (request.getParameter("submitted") != null){
    errors = user.validate();
    if (errors.size() == 0){
        // Если все ОК – переходим на следующую страницу
        response.sendRedirect("users.jsp");
        return;
    }
  }%>
```

Страница с ошибками input2.jsp:

```
<h2>User form</h2>
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="index.jsp">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
  <%if (errors != null && errors.size() > 0){%>
    <font color="red">
    <%for (java.util.Iterator iter = errors.entrySet().iterator();iter.hasNext();){%>
      <%=((java.util.Map.Entry)iter.next()).getValue()%><br>
    <%}%>
    </font>
  <%}%>
```

Подсветка полей:

```
<tr>
      <td>
        <%if (errors.containsKey("name")){%><font color="red"><%}%>
                Name *
        <%if (errors.containsKey("name")){%></font><%}%>
        </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=user.getName()%>">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

**Добавлено.**

Вот код user.java (есть get & set) в нем метод:

```
public Map validate()

    Map errors = new LinkedHashMap();
    if ("".equals(name)){
        errors.put("name", "Input the name, please");
    }
    if ("".equals(pswd)){
        errors.put("pswd", "Input the password, please");
    }
    if ("".equals(mail)){
        errors.put("mail", "Input the mail, please");
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Остальное не хватает места добавить

Comment: Подробнее, пожалуйста. Какие поля, какая валидация, что пробовали сделать, что не получилось, почему не получилось?

Comment: @maxus а в чем конкретно проблема? Ошибка компиляции, исключение, неправильная работа: пропускает недопустимые данные, не пропускает допустимые, не показывает ошибок? Меня смущает конструкция вида <%=user.getName()%>. Получается у вас к полю привязан только геттер. А что с сеттером? Быстрый гуглеж подсказывает, что `<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>` позволяет привязать инпуты к полям бина - так что аттрибут `value` задавать вообще не надо.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял, ошибка в самом последнем куске кода - метод **validate()**.

Я думаю корень бед - здесь:

```
 if ("".equals(name))
```

Получается, что вы вызываете у пустого объекта метод сравнения с ним. Для начала надо сделать хотя бы наоборот.

И вообще мне кажется, что эта строка должна выкидывать **NullPointerException**, хотя могу и ошибаться. Если вы хотите проверить строку на заполненность, то лучше попробуйте **name!=null**, а потом **name.isEmpty()** или **name.lenght()>0**.

Попробуйте, если что-то еще - будем копать дальше.

Comment: @Sasha121 вызов "anyString".equals(anyVar) позволяет как раз обеспечить отсутствие NPE - метод в любом случае вызовется не на null ("" - это не null, это просто строка). Но проверить на null и правда стоит - честно говоря, сам я начал прямо с JSF+Facelets, но может незаполненные поля в JSP принимают как раз значение null, а не ""?

Comment: @yozh сама валидация полей имя, пароль и е-мейл простой проверкой на !=null - это не правильно. Представь себе логин - 2 символа, пароль - 2 символа, а вместо электронного ящика указан почтовый индекс)))) А ведь пройдет валидацию!) Все-таки здесь надо проверять хотя бы на наличие минимум 3-4 символов и наличие в е-мейле @.

Comment: Я понимаю :) "Но проверить на null и правда стоит" - это к тому, что сравнение `"".equals(name)` приведет к тому, что name=null пройдет валидацию.

Comment: @yozh ты прав про NPE потому я так и сделал. С вопросом в общем то разобрался сам уже, с помощью товарища, всем спасибо за помощь!!!
P.S. По поводу "Представь себе логин - 2 символа, пароль - 2 символа, а вместо электронного ящика указан почтовый индекс))))" прикручиваю регулярные выражения.
P.P.S. "сравнение "".equals(name) приведет к тому, что name=null пройдет валидацию" у меня не проходит, это не регистрация новых пользователей, а вход в уже созданный аккаунт